# Possible cardinality of a set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This question comes from an exam and I can't find a nice solution,

> Consider the set $A=\{f:\omega \rightarrow \omega |f \space\text{ is  injective  and }\space f \subseteq S\}$. What are the possible infinite values of $|A|$ given $S \in \mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$?

I can easily get $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, but what about any cardinality $\kappa$ such that $\aleph_0 \lt \kappa \lt 2^{\aleph_0}$? My claim is that they can't be obtained, but any attempt to prove it failed. I tried also to show that it is indecidable, but I don't know I to proceed either (and also I don't really think that is the answer).

Thank you for your help

Comment: What $S$ gives $\aleph_0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Take an injection into the evens, say $x\mapsto 2x$, then let $S$ be the set of those ordered pairs, along with the pairs $(0,2n+1)$. This will also give you any finite value by limiting how many of these pairs are added (or remove $(0,0)$ to get the value $0$, obviously).

Comment: Here is some hint: if $A$ is infinite, then some section $S_n=\{m\mid (n,m)\in S\}$ must have at least two elements. Now divide the case as: first, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $|S_n|\ge 2$. Second, there are finitely many such.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this precisely the continuum hypothesis? That is, the statements "$|A|$ can only have 1 of two infinite values" and "$|A|$ can have more than two infinite values" are both independent (neither true nor false) in ZFC. Either can be taken as a new axiom to ZFC.

Comment: If a set is Borel, of analytic even, we can *prove* that its cardinality is countable or have size continuum. Regardless to CH. So the real question is whether or not you can say something like that about this set here.

Comment: No, it's not CH. "not CH" says precisely that there exists a set with cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $c$, but not that there is a set $A$ of the special form in the question with such a cardinality.

Comment: I am not following. It is not possible to show that there exists any set whatsoever of cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$, without "not CH". What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What you're misunderstanding is hard to say. You asked whether this was _precisely_ CH. The answer to that is no, although there _is_ an implication in one direction. Let's say a cardinal $\kappa$ is "exceptional" if $\aleph_0<\kappa<c$. CH say _there does not exist an exceptional cardinal. SH, the "S hypothesis", says that if $\kappa$ is an excpetional cardinal then there exists $S$ such that $|A|=\kappa$. It's clear that CH implies SH. But I have no idea why you would think that SH implies CH, so I can't point out the error in your reasoning.

Comment: In particular, your sentence above "It is not possible..." says that CH implies SH, but it says nothing about the converse.

Comment: I see your point, I guess I was assuming, CH and SH were the same. Doesn't the existence of a cardinal or some order imply that all sets of higher order contain a subset of that cardinal order? I thought this followed immediately since cardinals are subsets of each, defintionally.

Comment: Bobby, again, the point is not whether or not this contradicts CH (and thus not provable), but whether or not you can show that this set will *provably* always be countable or have size continuum (or come up with a consistency result where CH fails and for some set $S$, this set is also a counterexample to CH).